How to make VSCode warn me about missing libraries in a .fxml file?
When editing a .fxml file in InteliJ the IDE flags objects that don't have their libraries imported yet with the red underline, letting you simply hover it and import.
I've looked through the features of a bunch of VSCode's extensions and could not find something that does this.
Is there any way to achieve this in VSCode?

I'm not aware of any VS Code extension that understands FXML (beyond it being XML syntax) and can link it to Java types. If you want this then you may have to write your own extension.
